# Use of OWL inferences

Tags: owl, ontology

Are inferences in OWL made for use only in the construction and maintenance of an ontology, or can they also be useful in the system in which the ontology is inserted? If it is the second case, could you give an example? I don't know so many systems using ontologies, then I expect a clarification about the role of inferences in ontologies and ontology-based systems.

Comment: The second option is necessarily the case - if inferences were made only for maintaining ontologies, what would be the need for ontologies in the first place? Their added value over an ad hoc knowledge representation, such as that found in a database schema, is the automated and standardised inference of implicit information.

Answer (score 2):

Inferences are used extensively in the bioinformatics community where ontologies are used to infer classification hierarchies in the annotation of biological data. See for example the [Ontology Lookup Service (OLS)](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols4) (Disclaimer: I am a maintainer of OLS).

As an example, look at [liver disease](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols4/ontologies/efo/classes/http%253A%252F%252Fwww.ebi.ac.uk%252Fefo%252FEFO_0001421). On the righthand side you will see some of the axioms used in its definition. These are axioms used in inferring the hierarchical structure of the ontology and the placement of liver disease in the hierarchy :

[image]

How is this useful? When a user sees that some data is annotated with [EFO_0001421 (liver disease)](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols4/ontologies/efo/classes/http%253A%252F%252Fwww.ebi.ac.uk%252Fefo%252FEFO_0001421) they can get additional context information from the ontology. I.e., that liver disease is considered to be a digestive system disease and an endocrine system disease. Moreover, by looking at the children of liver disease, they can find all the diseases that are considered to be liver diseases.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. The example is great. When I mentioned an "example" in the second case, I was referring to a real world systems that make use of ontologies.

Comment: Define "real world example".  The example I have given is what is used to support various directions in biological research to inform drug targets and in  the treatment of patients.

Comment: Many thanks, the example was nice. By a "real world example" I referred to, for example, a ontology-based system working in a hospital. Thanks anyway!